# Would this wine recommendation question be on topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions, specific-question

Would the following question be on-topic for this site?

---

> I am looking for a red wine recommendation. The [Roman Rituale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_Ritual) of
> the Catholic Church has a special blessing which is reserved for the
> Feast of St John the Apostle (December 27). The actual blessing for
> the wine can be found on the [site](http://laudatedominum.net/files/freddofrog.pdf) (page 312).
>
> Why is wine associated with St John?
>
> > It is an old custom to drink of “St. John’s Love” by blessing wine on his feast day, December 27th.  According to legend St. John drank a
> > glass of poisoned wine without suffering harm because he had blessed
> > it before he drank. The wine is also a symbol of the great love of
> > Christ that filled St. John’s heart with loyalty, courage, and
> > enthusiasm. - [Gnostic Devotions](https://gnosticdevotions.wordpress.com/2013/12/27/blessing-of-the-wine-of-st-john/)
>
> Our Minister is okay with the idea but has set down a few desirable
> traits he would like to see with the wine. The Wine should have the
> following characteristics:
>
> 1. The wine should be red.
> 2. The price range should be no more than $20.00 a bottle.
> 3. The label should be modest and if possible make some sort of reference to St John if possible or some other religious theme, if a
>    St John theme cannot be found.
>
> Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recommendation questions are currently an [unresolved issue](https://alcohol.meta.stackexchange.com/q/164/43).  This happens on beta sites; we need to try things sometimes to see if they work.  Your question looks well-enough constrained to me (though are there any constraints about flavor, dry/sweet, etc?), so I'd say go ahead and ask it on main.

We *don't* want questions of the form "what's a good inexpensive wine?" (how should we know what you'll like?), but asking about wines (or beers or spirits or meads or ciders) that have certain properties seems ok to me, and as noted in the linked question, yours won't be the first.  Go ahead and ask it; you'll help us shape our scope, and I hope get some good answers.

Comment: Thanks, Monica. I will give it a shot and hope for the best!